# SIGABRT when switching views

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
@interface Objective_C_LibraryViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *enterSecondMenu;

}

-(IBAction)enterSecondMenu:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation Objective_C_LibraryViewController

-(IBAction)enterSecondMenu:(id)sender {
    SecondMainMenu *enterSecondMenu = [[SecondMainMenu alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];
    [self presentModalViewController: enterSecondMenu animated:YES];
}
```

When I press the UIButton that has the received outlet connected, it receives an SIGABRT.

Comment: if your are not loading SecondMainMenu from a nib, why not just use:
[[SecondMainMenu alloc]init]; ?

Comment: Is the view implemented properly in the .h file?

Comment: @Elmir your code is absolutly correct i run this code in my mac it's working fine, you do 1 thing check the connectivity of ibaction method with uibutton and also check the SecondMainMenu xib, is it properly having connected with file owner, try it and also reply the feed back

Answer (score 0):

the local var in your enterSecondMenu is named same as your IBOutlet property.  Change the code in the -(IBAction)enterSecondMenu:(id)sender to something like this:

```
SecondMainMenu *secondMenu = [[SecondMainMenu alloc]initWithNibName:Nil bundle:Nil];    
[self presentModalViewController: secondMenu animated:YES];
```

Comment: i have check ELMIR KOULIEV  code and it is working fine, local var name do not affect the ibaction method name. because both are different one is method and other is variable

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but is still fails to connect to the other view. I tried renaming the outlet and actions, but it made no difference, and my view are connected correctly.